# Difficulty extending Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I want to create an annotation handler to extend the Java language. However I can't do this easily, because of the SCL files. I wanted to know if the Lombok developers made it this hard on purpose.

If I try extending JavacAnnotationHandler, it can't find it in lombok.jar because the name is JavacAnnotationHandler.SCL.Lombok. I cloned the GitHub repository but I keep getting errors with duplicate classes in the resources.after and resources.before package and Java 12 syntax. I am using lombok 1.18.8.

This is what I have.

```
    import lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler;
    public class SingletonJavacHandler extends JavacAnnotationHandler<Singleton> {
```

It says "Cannot resolve symbol 'JavacAnnotationHandler'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SCL files are to hide lombok implementation classes from autocomplete dialogs in IDEs.

The resources-before and resources-after files should not be compiled. They are in the test resources, because our testing framework processes them.